# Can not get Fragment Tag That I set

Tags: android, android-fragments

I make a transition and then I gave a tag to the fragment while transition but
when I tried to find my fragment via tag fragment tag is null  here is my code

Main Activity.java

`HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment(); getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, homeFragment, HomeFragment.class.getName()).addToBackStack("HomeFragment");`

Then I go Home Fragment and pass Fragment manager to adapter

```
 homePageRecyclerViewAdapter = new HomePageRecyclerViewAdapter(AppRepository.get_instance().setMenuItems(), container.getContext(), requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
```

After that  I navigate to another fragment and I want to remove Home fragment
I want to find my fragment via tag but when I debug it  I check fragmentManager.getFragments() I see Home fragment but is tag is null

```
 String TAG = selectedFragment.getClass().getName();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainerView,selectedFragment,TAG).addToBackStack(TAG).commit();
    
    HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(HomeFragment.class.getName());

    if (homeFragment != null){

        fragmentTransaction.remove(homeFragment);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if it helps, but try to add a constant as you TAG variable and assign a string to it. Ex in kotlin:

```
const val TAG_HOME_FRAG: "Home Fragment"
```

And when making the transition and removing it, call the constant.

Comment: Why you think that Constant string is gonna change something also I set a string also didnt work